# snap package error: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

Tags: snap

I am trying to make a snap package for fotoxx. 
It seems I am 99% home.

If I enter the command "fotoxx" I get the following errors:

```
(process:27899): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
           Using the fallback 'C' locale. 
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module" 
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: 
No such file or directory 
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

However, if I execute the binary built by snapcraft, it works fine:

```
   $ .../snap/prime/usr/bin/fotoxx
```

As far as I can tell with only limited testing, the program works perfectly.

Only the command "fotoxx" fails.

I must be missing something in my snapcraft.yaml file. Here it is:

```
name: fotoxx
version: 16.07
summary: Edit photos and manage a large image collection. 
description: (omitted)
confinement: devmode
apps:
   fotoxx:
      command: fotoxx
parts:
   fotoxx:
      plugin: make
      source: /home2/mico/programs/fotoxx/packs/fotoxx-16.07.tar.gz
      stage-packages:
         - xdg-utils
         - libimage-exiftool-perl
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is missing or wrong on your side: there is still quite some work going on on desktop snaps and those warning/failure are part of them to this date.

The difference when you run (even in devmode) your snap via the command and directly `.../snap/prime/usr/bin/fotoxx` is that on the first case, all paths are fetching dependencies and assets like locale, modules and such, from your snap file (which doesn't have this `unity-gtk-module` for instance).
When you run your app directly from the `prime/` directory, it's like any another program on your system and it's using the system libraries.

To sum up, we track desktop-related issues [on this tag on our bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs?field.tag=snap-desktop-issue). The snappy and desktop team are currently on fixing those together!